# System Memory crash and CUDA Out of Memory Issues with BERT Model Classification

Tags: machine-learning, memory-management, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

Question:

I'm encountering memory-related issues when attempting to classify a large number of entries using a custom-trained BERT model. I've tried running the code both on my local system and Google Colab (with a GPU), but I'm consistently hitting memory limits. The project involves extracting text from scanned images pytesseract ocr engine and classifying them using bert(bert-base-uncased) transformer model. The inputs are in form of python dictionary where keys are page number and the values are extracted texts.
Here's an overview of the problem:
Local System:
OS: Windows 10
Python: 3.10.6
Successfully loaded the BERT model from Google Drive to VS Code.
The system crashes after classifying around 130 entries of 250 entries, with both memory and disk utilization at 100%.

Google Colab (T4 GPU):
CUDA Out of Memory Error encountered during the classification process of 250 entries.

Python Code:

Here's the code snippet I'm using:
input:

```
bert_input = {
    1: "Text for key 1",
    2: "Text for key 2",
    # entries up to 250
}
#model loading:
bert_model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("path to saved model in gdrive")
bert_tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("path to saved file in gdrive")

#classificatiprocessess:

def predict1(text):
    # Tokenization
    inputs = bert_token(text, padding=True, truncation=True, max_length=256, return_tensors="pt")

    # Get model output (logits)
    outputs = bert_model(**inputs)

    probs = outputs[0].softmax(1)

    pred_label_idx = probs.argmax()

    pred_label = bert_model.config.id2label[pred_label_idx.item()]

    return probs, pred_label_idx, pred_label

bert_output = {}
for key, text in bert_input.items():
    prediction_result = predict1(text)
    bert_output[key] = prediction_result
print("Bert output", bert_output)
```

Steps Taken:

I've tried batch processing with various batch sizes (30, 50, etc.), but the problem persists.
Deallocated used memory by setting variables to None and using the Python garbage collector (gc), but the issue was not resolved.
When decreasing the token size from 256 to 128, the model's performance was very low.

Specific Questions:

How can I optimize my code to classify a large number of entries using a BERT model without running into memory issues and system crashes to try in local windows machine?
Are there any best practices for handling GPU memory consumption when using BERT for classification?

Comment: The code you posted has a batch size of 1, but you mentioned that you tried different batch sizes. You are also not moving the input nor the model to the GPU or is bert_token a method? Can please post the actual code?